# How to use the SharePoint 2007 site content data in SharePoint 2013 site without migration?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How to use the SharePoint 2007 site content data in SharePoint 2013 site  without migration?

And what is the best practice if a client develop a new site in SharePoint 2013 environment but they want to use the SharePoint 2007 old content data in the new environment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to that question is not directly. You’ll have to upgrade your content and service applications(if required) through the process to get to 2010 and then to 2013.

Read this article by microsoft: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141.aspx